# Can't connect to remote ip

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to connect client with server. With local address (127.0.0.1) everything works perfectly fine, but when i try to use my remote address, it doesn't work. I search this thing all over the internet but i couldn't find anything.

Server side:

```
bool start_server()
{
    int i = 1;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WsaDat) != 0)
    {
         cout << "WSA error!" << endl;
         system("pause");
         return FALSE;
    }
    if ( LOBYTE( WsaDat.wVersion ) != 2 || HIBYTE( WsaDat.wVersion ) != 0 )
    {
      cout << "Bad version of winsocket" << endl;
      system("pause");
      WSACleanup();
      return 0;
    }



    serwer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serwer == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Can't create socketa!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    int port;
    cout << "Port input " << endl;
    cin >> port;                                             // 13056
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port =  htons(port);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    setsockopt( serwer, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, ( char * ) &i, sizeof ( i ) );
    if(bind(serwer,(SOCKADDR *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Couldn't bind socket" << endl;
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++)
    client[i].connected = FALSE;
    if(listen(serwer,SOMAXCONN)==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Listening error!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Serwer created!" << endl;
    unsigned long b = 0;
    ioctlsocket ( serwer, FIONBIO, &b );
    return 1;
}
```

After this i have accept function on which program is blocking:

```
accept(serwer,(SOCKADDR *)(&current_client->address),&current_client->address_length);
```

Client side:

```
bool start_client()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WsaDat) != 0)
        cout << "WSA error!\n";
    if ( LOBYTE( WsaDat.wVersion ) != 2 || HIBYTE( WsaDat.wVersion ) != 0 )
    {
        cout << "Wrong version of winsocket\n";
        WSACleanup();
                    return false;
    }

    SOCKET Klient;

    Klient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(Klient == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
        cout << "Can't create socket socketa!\n";
        WSACleanup();
                    return false;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);                        // 13056
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("*********");      // my remote address
    while(connect(Klient, (SOCKADDR *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0) 
    {
        cout << "Trying to connect " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        Sleep(500);
    }
    cout << "Connected!\n";
}
```

I have added both client and server applications to firewall rules and i have also tried to connect them on couple ports. Server side is listening for sure (here on different port):

[image]

Comment: Try removing the parts that are not absolutely necessary: The SO_REUSEADDR and FIONBIO. Then, which "remote address" are you connecting to? The ones that should work are the IP addresses attached to your local NICs, see the output of e.g. "ipconfig". Also, you could try to connect to some machine (e.g. a webserver) on the internet, at least you should be able to make a connection.

Comment: What error code is being returned by `WSAGetLastError()` when `connect()` fails?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - 10060 - Connection Timeout

Comment: @doomster - it's not it. 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.10 (my local addresses) works. When i try to do this with my ip checked on whatsmyip.org, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Blood: is your Internet modem connected directly to your PC, or to a network router?  If the latter, then you have to configure the router to port-forward inbound connections to the PC that is running your server app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

Not all routers and network address translators (NATs) support [hairpinning](http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/group__nat__intro.htm#hairpin), which is the ability to connect to your public IP from within the private network behind the NAT.

If your NAT/router does support this, then you likely will need to configure a port-forwarding rule on the NAT/route to map all incoming TCP traffic on port 14354 (your server listening port) to the internal IP address of 192.168.0.10.  Think of this from the router perspective, if it sees and incoming connection request on the public IP - it needs to know which host on the private network to forward that connection to.